# A problem with a trivial react native code with hooks

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

#### Update:

> Problem 2. is solved (thanks to @NikolayNovikov reply) by replacing "setResources({ resources: response.data })" with
>   "setResources(response.data)".
>
> Problem 1. I cannot reproduce it...

#### Description of the problem:

The following trivial example is fetching data from [jsonplaceholder.typicode.com](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/), and, since there are 100 'posts' and 200 'todos', it is supposed to display 100 and 200 when you click on these buttons.

For some reason that I cannot find (embarrassing, I know...), there are two problems:

1. When I click on the 'posts' button, useEffect is called twice (once with 'todos' and once with 'posts', and when I click on the 'todos' button it is not called at all.
2. resource.length is not rendered

Any idea what is wrong?

#### App.js:

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { ResourceList } from './components/ResourceList';

console.warn('In App.js: Disabling yellowbox warning in genymotion');
console.disableYellowBox = true;

```
export const App = () => {

  const [resource, setResource] = useState('todos');

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 100 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '500' }}>
        The Application has been loaded!
      </Text>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 100,
        alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setResource('posts')}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              Posts
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={{ width: 20 }} />
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setResource('todos')}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
              Todos
            </Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <ResourceList resource={resource} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  buttonText: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 20
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#a8a',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 5,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    borderRadius: 2
  }
});
```

#### ResourceList.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

// export const ResourceList = (props) => {
export const ResourceList = ({ resource }) => { // restructured props

  const [resources, setResources ] = useState([]);

  const fetchResource = async(resource) => {
    console.log('+++ ResourceList/fetchResource calling axios. path:',
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${resource}`);
    const response = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/${resource}`);
    console.log(response);
    setResources({ resources: response.data })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('--- ResourceList/useEffect. resource: ', resource);
    fetchResource(resource);
  }, [resource]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', marginTop: 100 }}>
      <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '500' }}>
        {resources.length}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `ResourceList.js` component `setResources` should be different, please try this:

```
setResources(response.data)
```